# How to logout facebook-connect PHP

Tags: php, facebook, logout

When I try to logout from facebook-connect PHP, it redirects me to the facebook profile page. I use this code to get the redirect URL:

```
$facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
    'next' => base_url().'access/'
));
```

Where base_url() is a personal function that returns 'localhost/myWebsite/'.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "localhost/myWebsite" could not recognized as an absolute path.
Do you tried "http://".base_url().'access/' on array ?

ex: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4760680/facebook-php-sdk-getlogouturl-problem

Comment: Sorry Claudson. Indeed, base_url() returns the absolute path http://localhost/myWebsite/ But it still doesn't work. I tried your link, but it's still not working.

Comment: Do you get url returns the method and used header("location: ...") to redirect ? Like http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8229869/getlogouturl-does-not-work ?

Comment: Yes. That's why I was redirected to facebook page.

Comment: Do you configured the app settings? I think that you only could redirect to logout to any domain.